# Middleware in express app, executed twice

Tags: express, router, middleware

For Some reason, my middleware is executed twice. Router is executed only once, but middleware twice. 
I tried to remove some .use to see if that helps, but I can't narrow it to anything. I don't know what is causing it.

//route

```js
import { Router } from 'express'

export default Router({ mergeParams: true }).post(
  '/v1/tickets/createTicket',
  async (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({message: success})
  }
)
```

//router - dynamically created

```
export default () =>
  sync('**/*.js', { cwd: `${__dirname}/` })
    .map((filename) => require(`./${filename}`).default)
    .filter((router) => Object.getPrototypeOf(router) === Router)
    .reduce(
      (rootRouter, router) =>
        rootRouter
          .post('/v1/tickets/createTicket', isAuthenticated)
          .use(router),
      Router({ mergeParams: true })
    )
```

//middleware

```
export default async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.path)
  return next()
}
```

// express app

```
export default ({ logger }) =>
  express()
    .use(
      expressWinston.logger({
        winstonInstance: logger,
        msg:
          '{{res.statusCode}} {{req.method}} {{req.url}} {{res.responseTime}}ms',
        meta: false
      })
    )
    .use(urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    .use(json())
    .use(cors())
    .use('/api', router)
    .use((err, req, res, next) => {
      if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
        logger.error('Incorrect body structure')
        return res.sendStatus(400) // Bad request
      }
      let errorMessage = { error: err.error || err }
      logger.error(errorMessage.error)
      res.status(err.code || 500).json(errorMessage)
      res.end()
    })
```

output in console is:

```
/v1/tickets/createTicket
/v1/tickets/createTicket
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're sending `.post(
  '/v1/tickets/createTicket',` in your `route` and then again in your `router` - `rootRouter
          .post('/v1/tickets/createTicket', isAuthenticated)`. Could that be the reason?

Comment: It might be that, but, how am I supposed to hook middleware before that path, I have routes in separated files. I thought it supposed to execute middleware, then got next() to my route where I do actual stuff for that path.